# Configuring Apache virtual hosts in extra file

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I have access to a machine running linux. Apache2 is installed on it. I need to add 3 virtual hosts.

In `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, there is a set of about 15 files displayed with `ls -la`.

1. I was told Apache2 would read these files one-by-one in alphabetic order to create virtual hosts, is this correct?
2. How does Linux give preference in case of conflict? Last read file wins? First read file wins?
3. If I want to configure my 3 virtual hosts (which are not in conflict with existing virtual hosts), is it just a matter of creating an extra file with them in this directory?

**P.S.:** I have mixed-up `available` with `enabled`. One should read `/etc/apache2/enabled`. Sorry.

Comment: Please check if you have `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` with symlinks to `../sites-available`. (Is this SuSE Linux?)

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read the Apache2 documentation.

**I was told Apache2 would read these files one-by-one in alphabetic order to create virtual hosts, is this correct?**

Virtual hosts are not read in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` but in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. That said, apache2 uses the libc, and according to [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Simple-Directory-Lister.html), *The order in which files appear in a directory tends to be fairly random*.

## edit:

You may want to read the answer from @nwildner too which is more accurate than me.

**How does Linux give preference in case of conflict? Last read file wins? First read file wins?**

Really not sure, but if there is a conflict, generally it displays a warning message and your httpd service won't (re)load.

**If I want to configure my 3 virtual hosts (which are not in conflict with existing virtual hosts), is it just a matter of creating an extra file with them in this directory?**

Yes, and once you've added your extra files, run these commands:

```
sudo a2ensite my_site1.conf my_site2.conf my_site3.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

It will search in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` for `my_site1.conf`, `my_site2.conf` and `my_site3.conf`.

Comment: I believe your meant it will search `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` for `my_site1.conf` etc..

Comment: Nope, because a2ensite means "Apache2 enable site", its role will be to create a symbolic link from `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. But you can absolutely do it manually, or create your file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. But that's not recommended because it's hard if you want to quickly temporarily disable your site by keeping the vhost.

Answer (score 3):

Answer your question heavily depends on the distribution you are using. I will assume it´s Debian based, since they use this approach of `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` dirs and the `/etc/apache2` configuration dir instead of `/etc/httpd` like the RPM based distributions.

**Answer 1.** That is correct. You can see the `Include` directive on your `apache2.conf` file:

```
host:/etc/apache2# grep sites apache2.conf
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

Taking  a look at the Apache Include directive [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include):

> ... Shell-style (fnmatch()) wildcard characters can be used in the
>   filename or directory parts of the path to include several files at
>   once, **in alphabetical order**. ...

**Answer 2.** Not sure what will happen. I have duplicated on purpouse a VirtualHost on my Apache server and it did not complained about it. Not sure if first or last configuration was set as valid.

**Edit1**: It seems CentOS Apache uses the first entry of the `VirtualHost` configured, when i put 2 of the same VirtualHost inside `/etc/httpd/conf.d/virtual_host.conf` changing only the `DocumentRoot`. Config example:

```
<VirtualHost ip.address.A:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/wpad
  ServerName wpad.xxx.net
  ServerAlias wpad.xxx.net wpad
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ip.address.A:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/wpad2
  ServerName wpad.xxx.net
  ServerAlias wpad.xxx.net wpad
</VirtualHost>
```

When i browse on Incognito/Private browser mode, i get the `wpad.xxx.net/wpad.dat` file that is provided by the first `virtualhost`. No errors found on Apache logs.

**Answer 3.** On Debian based distribution you have to create the file inside `sites-available` and symlink it to `sites-enabled`

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
ln -s your-site ../sites-enabled/
```

Or, you could use `a2ensite` as explained by @Sw0ut

Comment: Thanks, I will create it in `/sites-enabled`